# QGIS python QDialog qgis-bin.exe - критическая ошибка

Tags: python, плагин, qgis

Тестовый плагин

```
def run(self):
    """Action to run"""
    infoString = "This is a test"
    QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(),"About",infoString)
```

Работает нормально, но если запустить:

```
def run(self):
    """Action to run"""
    GUIEnabled=True
    app = QgsApplication([], GUIEnabled)

    dlg = QDialog()
    dlg.exec_()
```

QGIS-bin.exe выдает критическую ошибку после закрытия `QDialog`. Я все сделал по поваренной книге QGIS. Кто нибудь знает в чем моя ошибка?
(QGIS 2.14.0 - essen)

Comment: решено:  dlg = QDialog()
                dlg.exec_() - оставить только.